# How to have an image incorporate in my text ? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my website and I would like to have a nice quotation. To do that, I'd like to have two big quotation marks images at the beginning and the end of my text, like incorporated in the text, that would move with the text when I resize the window.

I've tried to use a span with a display: block and the image as background but it acts like a div.

If I use a div and margins to place it right, it stays at the same place when I resize the window and is no more align with my text.

What would you advise ?

EDIT

Here is what I would like :

[image: quotation]

Comment: Use pseudo-elements. However, it would be nice to show us your markup.

Comment: There you go, I've added an image to show you what I'd lile

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/bmcz6uxh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a span was the correct choice but you should set it to `inline` or `inline-block` (or leave it alone altogether). As you found out, setting it to block made it occupy the entire width.

If you can use something other than an image, you can put a span around the quote character itself and use any unicode or other font family for quotation marks. Then you can put a span just around that and set it however you wish while maintaining an inline textual quote.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this raw css, you can customized it as you want.

```css
html {
    background: gray;
}
blockquote {
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 30px
}
blockquote:before {
    content: '"';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 48px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;

}
blockquote:after {
    content: '"';
    position: absolute;    
    font-size: 48px;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
This is a sample of a blockquote.
</blockquote>
```

EDIT: 
The above code works with a fixed quotations on the `blockquote` itself, the ending quotation doesn't move on the end of the paragraph.

This one should do it.

```css
html {
    background: gray;
}
blockquote {
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 30px
}
.ql,.qr {
    position: relative;
}
.ql:before,.qr:after {
    content: '"';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 48px;
}
.ql:before {
    top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <span class="ql"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I am a sample of blockquote with a big quotation marks.<span class="qr"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <span class="ql"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I am a sample of blockquote with a big quotation marks. You see it moves according to the length of what I'm saying.<span class="qr"></span>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: The quotation marks is not an image, therefore it adapts to what font you attached to it. Note that different fonts has its different viewspace so adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

How about this..

```
<p class="your-quote-wrapper">
   <span><img src="/quote-icon-left.png"></span>Blabla blabla text<span><img src="/quote-icon-right.png"></span>
</p>
```

And your span being `inline-block`

```
p.your-quote-wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a span? Why not apply the CSS just to the img?

Comment: @Rob being all inline would bring all element at same level and lower chances of distorting. what you mean "applying css to img" ? sorry didn't get that

Comment: If you apply that CSS to the image, and leave the span out of it, you'd accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Rob yeah, correct. It's just a wrapper as he has mentioned in question he is using `span`. Also with being those spans `inline-block` one can assign height width and use image from css if using image this way looks not so clean

Comment: Inline-block is the right answer. Didn't use the <img> to have the image in background :) Thank you all !